# An error occurred when attempting to recursively print all file paths in a given directory

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to recursively print all of the file paths from a directory

```
try {
  Files.walkFileTree(Utils.getContentDirectory().toPath(), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() { //**Exception here**

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                
      Utils.log(file.toString());    
      return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;

    }  
  });
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is the directory I'm trying to read from, which does exist (I'm using maven and it's an internal directory)

```
public static File getContentDirectory() {
    return new File(UltimateBugTracker.class.getClassLoader().getResource("resources/html/index.html").getFile()).getParentFile();
}
```

but for whatever reason it's throwing this exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4: file:\C:\Users\raz\Desktop\WebServer.jar!\resources\html

which doesn't make sense because I'm using the build in `fileInstance.toPath()` method to get the path. I don't understand why it is saying that it's an invalid path.

Comment: Are there any compressed files in your search directory, such as a `jar` or `zip`? Not sure if this is the problem because the exception doesn't say `jar:file...` for example. They would be valid `URI`s, but not valid `Path`s or `File`s. It could also be that the path contains `\`. Try `resources\\html\\index.html`.

Comment: `file:\C:\Users\raz\Desktop\WebServer.jar!\resources\html` is a URL and not a path. The error message clearly states that the colon character appearing after the word `file` is unexpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing a valid Path to walkFileTree, but a URI for a resource within a jar. Hopefully this example makes it clearer on how to walk the resources within your jar vs files in a directory:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    var jar = Path.of("C:\\Users\\raz\\Desktop\\WebServer.jar");

    System.out.println("isRegularFile()="+Files.isRegularFile(jar));

    FileVisitor<? super Path> visitor = new FileVisitor<Path>()
    {
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException
        {
            System.out.println("dir START "+dir);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException
        {
            System.out.println("file "+file);
           return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException
        {
            System.out.println("file fail "+file);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
        public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException
        {
            System.out.println("dir END "+dir);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    };

    try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(jar))
    {
        Path path = fs.getPath("/resources/html");

        System.out.println("walkFileTree within archive "+ jar+" starting at path: "+path);

        Files.walkFileTree(path, visitor);
    }

    Path parent = jar.getParent();
    System.out.println("walkFileTree at "+ parent);
    Files.walkFileTree(parent, visitor);
}
```